# PayPal from NuGet

Tags: paypal, nuget-package

I added PayPal from NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal/ to my solution but on runtime I get an error

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'PayPalCoreSDK, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5b4afc1ccaef40fb' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'PayPalCoreSDK, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5b4afc1ccaef40fb'
```

Any Idea to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message you seem to be using the incorrect nuget package.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'PayPalCoreSDK'
```

You should use [PayPal Core SDK for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPalCoreSDK/) instead of [PayPal .NET SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal/)